# Deploy webapp on embedded tomcat7 with maven ?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to deploy my spring-based web app on embedded tomcat7 server using maven. Below is the maven configuration for tomcat7 maven plugin :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>
<port>9090</port>
<path>/</path>
<addContextWarDependencies>true</addContextWarDependencies>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I access `http://localhost:9090` , the app is not completly deployed (I only see the app title in the header). For starting up the embedded server and deploy the app , I used

```
mvn clean install tomcat7:run
```

What is the correct maven configuration to achieve this ? (if there is one)

Comment: have you considered using cargo? it should work with tomcat 7 and tomcat 8.

Comment: I googled it a bit ( i did not know about cargo ) and I don't think it fits my purpose . I need to deploy the app on an embedded tomcat . From what i've seen , cargo helps me deploy to a standalone tomcat installation.Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you have any special Maven executions? Because `tomcat7:run` doesn't use all build phases.

Comment: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin
That command will automatically download Tomcat 7.0.16 from the specified URL (taking into account any proxy server setting you would have in Maven2/Maven3), instantiate the container, create a local configuration with your application and run it. It will also save the downloaded container in the default directory (see the Maven2 Plugin Reference Guide for details), so it won't get downloaded when you run the same command twice.

Comment: i have a sample here: https://github.com/ttwd80/qir/blob/master/pom.xml
mvn clean package cargo:run
i hook this up with http://drone.io
what happens is that drone.io will build the war, start tomcat and run the selenium tests

Comment: [This](http://www.javacreed.com/how-to-run-embedded-tomcat-with-maven/) example can be useful to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but none of them fits my purpose as I had to use only the tomcat plugin for maven 
The following configuration alongside with **mvn clean install tomcat7:run** command will deploy your app in an embedded tomcat 
`<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>
<port>9090</port>
<path>/</path>
<contextFile>"path to context file"</contextFile>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>run</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>`